# Unable to control "switchover" for AWS RDS blue green deploy via terraform

Tags: terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws, blue-green-deployment

We are trying implement blue green deploy via terraform for our RDS instances. The blue green deploy is working successfully. However, few of our databases are pretty big where ETL jobs run periodically.  Currently, when we are enabling blue green deploy, it is implementing all the steps including switchover and deletion of older database.

I am trying to find a way to control the switchover and do that part manually. Is there a way to just create the blue green  deployment via terraform and do the switchover manually?

We enabled the blue green option

```
 blue_green_update = {
    enabled = true
    password_changes = false
}
```

terraform-aws-rds module version 5.4.0